# How to use ivhtree bread first search api

Tags: angularjs, tree, treeview, breadth-first-search, treecontrol

i am trying to use ivhTreeviewBfs (https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview#ivhtreeviewbfstree-opts-cb)

```
ivhTreeviewBfs(myTree, function(node) {
  console.log(node)
})
```

however this only prints the first level of nodes. How can i traverse through the entire list?

Comment: please provide more detail, a plunk at least !

Comment: you can checkout example here http://jsbin.com/wofunu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue.
After some research and testing it seems that this behavior occurs when you override the default attribute for the children via `ivh-treeview-children-attribute`.

The service doesn't detect any children anymore (`undefined`), hence only process the first level.

This [demo](http://jsbin.com/yomijakiju/1/edit?html,js,output) (forked from @ua_boaz's link) illustrates the issue.

I am still trying to figure out how to fix it.

**UPDATE:** [This issue](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/issues/106) reports a similar problem. A workaround is to set the `childrenAttribute` globally using the `ivhTreeviewOptionsProvider`, [demo here](http://jsbin.com/xasumaqila/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: i figured out the issue long time ago, forgot to update this. thanks